# Element choice in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am creating JAXB classes that may relate to either one of the below XML elements:

```
<Request>
  <Details/>
  <Option1/>
</Request>

<Request>
  <Details/>
  <Option2/>
</Request>
```

In other words, the Option1 and Option2 elements are both optional inside the Request class, but one **must** exist for the XML to be valid - like an exclusive OR. Is there a JAXB annotation I can use in my Request class to specify this? Or any other work around?

Comment: _At least one_ is not exclusive `or`. :)

Comment: my apologies - **only one** must exist.

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a [callback method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) in the `Request` class and perform the validation programmatically:

```
private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
   if ((option1 == null) == (option2 == null)) {
      throw new ValidationException();
   }
}
```